# Trying to perform addition of two fractional fixed_point operands in VERILOG, I'm stuck in this error

Tags: math, verilog, fractions, fixed-point

I'm trying to write a Verilog synthesizable program for adding two fractional fixed_point numbers. This is the test bench:

```
module sum_test;

// Inputs
reg [12:-20] oper1;
reg [12:-20] oper2;
reg cin;

// Outputs
wire [12:-20] sum_result;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
sum_fix uut (
    .oper1(oper1), 
    .oper2(oper2), 
    .cin(cin), 
    .sum_result(sum_result)
);

initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    oper1 = 0;
    oper2 = 0;
    cin = 0;

    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
    #100;

    // Add stimulus here
oper1 = 12.5;
oper2 = 5.4;

end

initial begin
    $monitor("oper1=%d,oper2=%d,sum_result=%d \n",oper1,oper2,sum_result);      

end

endmodule
```

/// This is the addition module

```
module sum_fix(

input [12:-20] oper1,
input [12:-20] oper2,
input cin,
output [12:-20] sum_result
);

assign sum_result = oper1 + oper2 + cin;
endmodule
```

Simulator print this,

oper1=         0,oper2=         0,sum_result=         0

oper1=        13,oper2=         5,sum_result=        18

It seems I'm not introducing the numbers correctly in the testbench or something, it might be that simulator can't work with this notation? BTW I made this module inspired in the book "Digital Design (Verilog)" of Ashenden. He speaks about this fixed-point fractional notation and even make an addition like me with the operator "+", so I don't know what's wrong, he didn't make test bench for this example, though. Thank you everybody, this forum rocks.

Comment: Where did you get the `[12:-20]` notation from?

Comment: Hey Morgan, I got it from the book "Digital Design: An Embedded Systems Approach Using Verilog" by Peter J. Ashenden, 2008. It's interesting I have asked a friend about it, and he didn't know this notation aswell, now you tell me you are not familiarized with it? (i.e page 159)

Comment: I have never seen negative indexes used before. If it works great but not sure I would trust it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using :

```
reg [32:0] oper1;
reg [32:0] oper2;
```

instead of :

```
reg [12:-20] oper1;
reg [12:-20] oper2;
```

And stimulus is :

```
oper1 = 12.5 * 2**20; //shift 20 binary places
oper2 = 5.4  * 2**20;
```

Comment: It prints this: oper1=  13107200,oper2=   5662310,sum_result=  18769510 , I think Simulator interpret it as I'm saying ------   oper1 = 125 * (2^20); oper2 = 54 * (2^20);

Comment: @sujeto1 18769510 *2^-20 = 17.9 which looks correct to me (12.5+5.4)!